# 2 pair Ethernet connection not working, but 4 pair does

Tags: ethernet, internet-connection, cable

I'm having problems with my internet connection. I have 2-pair lan cable, it used to work before in my PC, but 4 days back it stopped working, it works in others PC. Now only 4 pair lan connection works in my PC.

**Laptop:**  HP pavilion dv6

**Driver:**  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Driver

**Internet Cable:**  1-2-3-6 2-pair cable

connection provided by ISP.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: For Gigabit Ethernet you need 4 pairs and you have a GbE NIC; maybe your NIC speed is not set to 100 Mbit/s

Comment: Ashtray, if you are talking about the settings in the network adapter(the driver in the device manager of Win8), i have tried changing the speed settings.

Comment: Did you try contacting your ISP? Maybe they have some sort of MAC address count limitation on their ports or other stuff.

Comment: I contacted them, they said it is clear on their end!

Comment: Can you exclude NIC failure on your PC? Or some sort of duplex,mdix mismatches? Hadn't you changed anything just before it failed? What's different about PCs where it does work?

Comment: i haven't changed anything before my it failed. I think my laptop isn't able to supple enough power for the ethernet connections of long length. short length ethernet wires are working for the port.